# Got Error: Unknown command: linkapps when running r

Tags: r, homebrew

I installed r with brew. When I run `r` or `brew linkapps r`, I got the error: Unknown command: linkapps. How do I fix it?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1346236/homebrew-linkapps-command-not-found-what-can-replace-it-so-i-can-use-macvim-a

Comment: @RobertHarvey It works when running `r` directly, it is that running r repeated the previous command `brew linkapps r`.